# How to fix mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter

Tags: php, mysqli

When I run this code I give this error:

> mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Its for `$insert_stmt->execute()` I don't know why I have this error, because database and table is true and all of 4 values have sting

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password,salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

    $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);

    // Execute the prepared query.
    if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
        echo mysqli_stmt_error();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function needs the statement also.

```
mysqli_stmt_error($yourstatement).
```

Check it here - [mysqli_stmt_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up object-oriented and procedural style usage of MySQLi in your code.

Object oriented-stlye:

```
echo $insert_stmt->error;
```

Procedural style:

```
echo mysqli_stmt_error($insert_stmt);
```

You are using the latter, but not giving it an argument. I advise you to use the object-oriented way as you are doing it in other parts of your code.